# WCF Returning Object of a type from a Referenced Assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf

I have looked at some similar posts about this topic and didn't quite find what I was looking for so I'll explain what I'm doing and the problem I'm running in too.

I have a MVC3 application and a class library which holds my model data.  For example my domain model project has a class called CLUser here:

```
public class CLUser
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = Util.ERRORMESSAGE_STRING_LENGTH_50)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime PasswordExpiration { get; set; }
    public bool LockedOut { get; set; }
    public string LockedOutReason { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Security Question")]
    public string SecurityQuestion { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Security Answer")]
    public string SecurityAnswer { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Current Status:")]
    public int Standing { get; set; }
    public int MerchantID { get; set; }
    public int PartnerID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDtTm { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDtTm { get; set; }
    public List<CLPermission> UserPerms { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a WCF Service which references the same project that has the model CLUser.  So in my WCF I have an operation contract called

```
[OperationContract]
GetUser(string userName, string password);
```

and is thus exposed in MVC project.

So here is the problem.  I want to set CLUser object equal to my WCF service call for GetUser.  Which looks like this:

```
ServiceClient MyService = new ServiceClient();
CLUser Usr = MyService.GetUser(userName, password);
```

However, when I do I get an error like so:

Cannot implicitly convert type Auth.CLUser to Auth.CLUser[C:\ ....\Auth.DLL]

If the WCF and the MVC application both reference the same DLL wouldn't they be able to use the same objects?

Comment: Try to rebuild the DLL, build the service, start the service, update the service reference, build the client.

Comment: Ok I will that today and see if it works.

Comment: OK Well I feel silly.  The reason I was getting that error was because when I added my service, I was giving the service the same assembly name as my WCF project.  So that's why it got confused.  Simply re-adding the service under a different assembly name fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you're loading the same assembly from different locations then types may not be seen as equal depending on the load context used. Identity is sometimes more than a strong name.

- Assembly Identity:
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/07/21/57232.aspx
- LoadFile vs LoadFrom:
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom.aspx
- Choosing a Binding Context:
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As @JohnSaunders eluded to in the question comments, make sure you're referencing the same version of the common assembly. If the model is different then deserializing the WCF messaging won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a generated proxy of `ServiceClient`, which will have created a structurally identical but different type of `CLUser` (the type will live in a different namespace), and trying to use its return value as a reference to the shared assembly type `CLUser`. If you have a ServiceReference in your project to ServiceClient, that results in this problem. You can use something like [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map the content from the generated proxy type to your preferred shared type, or use [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx) to create the client connection, which will then return your shared assembly CLUser type. Personally I prefer the `ChannelFactory` approach.